# jQuery toggle and slideup?

Tags: jquery, toggle

```
$('.rs-expand').hide();
$('.rs-details').click(function(){
    $('.rs-expand').slideUp('fast');
    $('.rs-s li').removeClass('toggled');
    $(this).parent().find('.rs-expand').toggle('blind', 200);
    $(this).parent().addClass('toggled');
});
```

Where do I add or how so that if click again, it will slideUp?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="rs-s">
  <li> 
    <div class="rs-details">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <div class="rs-expand"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML source code

Comment: <ul class="rs-s">
<li>
<div class="rs-details">
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
 <div class="rs-expand">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.rs-expand').hide();
$('.rs-details').click(function(){
    $('.rs-expand').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).children('.rs-expand').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B4Kjs/2/

Comment: no that won't work, because if you click it it will just expand then collapse right after

Comment: try to remove $(this).parent().find('.rs-expand').toggle('blind', 200);

Comment: basically we need this function, http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/collapsible.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.rs-details').toggle(function(){
    $(this).find('div').slideToggle('fast');
    $(this).parent('li').removeClass('toggled');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('div').slideToggle('fast');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('toggled');
  });
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/B4Kjs/

Comment: basically we need the same function as this, jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/collapsible.html

Answer (score 0):

Revised code. This should trim your needs waaay down.

**CSS Styling:**

```
.rs-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.rs-details').click(function(){
    $('.rs-expand').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

[See Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ydpkg6vp/)